# On ping first packet fails

Tags: networking, ping, packet-loss

I am trying to ping a virtual machine.The first packet always fails and rest all packets are recieved.The DNS of the virtual machine is configured manually.Can someone help on what can be the issue

Comment: We'll need more information than this.  What vm, what host, what OS, what networking method.

Comment: The host OS is Windows server 2003,Vmware is used and the guest OS is Windows xp.The VM is stored on a server in a LAN.**The issue is resolved on adding static ARP**.But if possible i want to know why it was failing with dynamic arp.Adding to this,there are other similar VM's configured on the same server and they are working fine with the dynamic ARP

Comment: So it is an arp timeout issue - the arp reply is coming later than the ping is willing to wait.  I would use wireshark and see what is taking so long.

Comment: Thanks Paul...i will try looking into it and will provide you with results....